# How to make the child of a spawned player gameobject to be private to the player using Photon Unity Networking implementing Multiplayer Game on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

Using the photon Unity Networking, I am spawning the player game object in a multiplayer unity game. This spawned player game objects are cloned to all devices playing that game and joined same room.

**My question is that how to make a particular game object which is a child of the spawned player game object completely private to the player which spawns that child game object. Nobody else can view it.**

Answer (score 0):

When you Instantiate the players, instead of calling the object to instantiate on network use regular unity instantiation, just make sure that the object you are instantiating does not contain a PhotonView or anything similar.

Comment: I confirm this is one possible way, but another way that might be easier for the prefab structure is to check on the .IsMine flag, you delete that private object or not. so when .IsMine is false, the child is deleted, and thus only the owner will have it.